# How to get structured data of companies on wikipedia using dbpedia?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get the structured data of a companies from wikipedia. I have company names, but they are according to their listings name in SEC. I want to search those companies structured data on wikipedia using DBPedia. I know that all companies on SEC are not on Wiki, but I want to do this for the companies which are there on wikipedia.

I have found that we can do this by making requests like this: https://dbpedia.org/page/Apple_Inc.

However, this requires the name `Apple_Inc` in above url to be perfectly correct. I do not have any mappings of companies in SEC to companies in wiki. Is there any known approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wikidata has a [property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P5531) for SEC ID so you can search for the article title based on that ([example](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Ftitle%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP5531%20%220000831001%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aname%20%3Ftitle%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%5B%20wikibase%3AwikiGroup%20%22wikipedia%22%20%5D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%2010)).

I'd imagine there is some equivalent way of searching by the SEC key in DBPedia but I'm not familiar with that project.

Answer (score 0):

If the SEC Central Index Key (CIK) data doesn't exist on DBpedia, you can use a federated SPARQL query to grab results from a Wikidata SPARQL endpoint (i.e., the SEC IDs in @tgr's answer), and then reconcile the results with company data from a DBpedia Endpoint, via **owl:sameAs** relations:

```
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT 
    ?wdCompany 
    ?dbpCompany 
    ?key

WHERE
    {
        #Get SEC Data, add what you might want to find in Wikidata here
        SERVICE <http://query.wikidata.org/sparql>
        {
            ?wdCompany wdt:P5531 ?key .
        }

        #Add what you want to find in DBPedia to this Query
        SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
        {
            ?dbpCompany owl:sameAs ?wdCompany.
        }
    }
```

- [Live Query Definition](https://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3FwdCompany%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3FdbpCompany%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fkey%0A%0AWHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23Get%20SEC%20Data%2C%20add%20what%20you%20might%20want%20to%20find%20in%20Wikidata%20here%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FwdCompany%20wdt%3AP5531%20%3Fkey%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23Add%20what%20you%20want%20to%20find%20in%20DBPedia%20to%20this%20Query%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbpCompany%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3FwdCompany.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)
- [Live Query Result](https://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+wdt%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%0D%0A++++%3FwdCompany+%0D%0A++++%3FdbpCompany+%0D%0A++++%3Fkey%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++%23Get+SEC+Data%2C+add+what+you+might+want+to+find+in+Wikidata+here%0D%0A++++++++SERVICE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E%0D%0A++++++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++%3FwdCompany+wdt%3AP5531+%3Fkey+.%0D%0A++++++++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++++++++%23Add+what+you+want+to+find+in+DBPedia+to+this+Query%0D%0A++++++++SERVICE+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql%3E%0D%0A++++++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++%3FdbpCompany+owl%3AsameAs+%3FwdCompany.%0D%0A++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000000)

Building on the 1st SERVICE clause's query will modify query criteria against Wikidata.

Building on the 2nd SERVICE clause's query will modify the query criteria against DBpedia.